# Adding frame over lable on python

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I want to create frame over the label and been trying lots of code but it is not working out. Also trying to make checkbutton to left side of the screen with no frame. Can anyone help me? Thank you

I got far as this
[image: 1st Try]

But I want to make it look like this with the frame

[image]

```
show_status = Label(dashboard, bd = 5, text = 'Even', fg = 'black',
                        font = ('Arial', 70), width = 8)

def update_dashboard():

three_buttons = Label(dashboard, relief = 'groove')

Alpha_button = Checkbutton(three_buttons, text = 'Alpha',
                              variable = alpa_1,
                              command = update_dashboard)

Beta_button = Checkbutton(three_buttons, text = 'Beta',
                           variable = beta_2, 
                           command = update_dashboard)

Gamma_button = Checkbutton(three_buttons, text = 'Gamma',
                           variable = gemma_3, 
                           command = update_dashboard)


Alpha_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'w')
Beta_button.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = 'w')
Gamma_button.grid(row = 1, column = 4, sticky = 'w')

margin = 5 # pixels

show_status.grid(padx = margin, pady = margin, row = 1,
                     column = 1, columnspan = 2,)
three_buttons.grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky = W)


dashboard.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Frame or a Canvas  and draw the rest of the widgets on it. Let us use the Frame by relying on the [grid layout manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).

To have that effect you are looking for, you simply need to span the label over the 3 columns of the check button widgets using the option the [`columnspan`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method) option.

## Full program

Here is a simple solution using the object oriented concepts:

```
'''
Created on May 8, 2016

@author: Billal Begueradj
'''
import Tkinter as Tk


class Begueradj(Tk.Frame):
    '''
    Dislay a Label spanning over 3 columns of checkbuttons
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        '''Inititialize the GUI
        '''
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize_user_interface()

    def initialize_user_interface(self):
        """Draw the GUI
        """
        self.parent.title("Billal BEGUERADJ")       
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.config(background="lavender")    

        # Create a Frame on which other elements will be attached to
        self.frame = Tk.Frame(self.parent, width = 500, height = 207)  
        self.frame.pack(fill=Tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)   

        # Create the checkbuttons and position them on the second row of the grid
        self.alpha_button = Tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, text = 'Alpha', font = ('Arial', 20))
        self.alpha_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        self.beta_button = Tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, text = 'Beta', font = ('Arial', 20))
        self.beta_button.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        self.gamma_button = Tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, text = 'Gamma', font = ('Arial', 20))
        self.gamma_button.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

         # Create the Label widget on the first row of the grid and span it over the 3 checbbuttons above
        self.label = Tk.Label(self.frame, text = 'Even', bd = 5, fg = 'black', font = ('Arial', 70), width = 8, relief = 'groove')
        self.label.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 3)



# Main method
def main():
    root=Tk.Tk()
    d=Begueradj(root)
    root.mainloop()

# Main program       
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

## Demo

Here is a screenshot of the running program:

[image]

Comment: Thank it helped alot